# How to configure Apache to automatically restart itself every N requests?

Tags: windows, apache-2.2, svn

We host svn on Apache 2.2 and [it's memory usage slowly grows](https://serverfault.com/questions/125301/apache-2-2-used-to-provide-access-to-svn-consumes-a-lot-of-memory) until it just halts. I've heard that there's a magic settings that makes Apache restart itself automatically after processing every N requests.

Does this setting exist? Where can I learn more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, for learning more you could certainly do worse that looking at the [official Apache 2.2 documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/).

Specifically in this case, it seems you're looking for the [MaxRequestsPerChild](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html#maxrequestsperchild) directive.

Comment: Great... Except that we already had that settings (every 512 requests) and it doesn't help...

Answer (score 1):

How quickly does the issue become a problem?

If the child cycling options (as suggested by janneb) do not work around the leak, you could set a scheduled task to restart the service daily/weekly. Under Linux the command to schedule would be `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`, under Windows it would probably be `net start apache` followed by `net start apache` or similar.

Comment: The problem surfaces about every two weeks. We'll think of employing this suggestion. The problem is we have very little experience running Apache, so we'd rather not rush into anything.